# Ruby: How does implicit return value work in blocks?

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

**EDIT:** My original question turned out not to be related to my actual problem, but as I learned something in the process, I decided to rephrase my initial statement.

I wanted to replace each space  with a `_` within a pair of brackets in a string. Here is my example input:

```
This is my string (nice, isn't it?). It can have various types [of input].
```

Desired output:

```
This is my string (nice,_isn't_it?). It can have various types [of_input].
```

I have the following code:

```
my_string = my_string.gsub(/\([^\(\)]+\)|\[[^\[\]]+\]/) { |bracketed|
    bracketed.gsub(/ /, '_')
}
```

Why does `bracketed.gsub(/ /, '_')` equal to `bracketed = bracketed.gsub(/ /, '_')`? How is that different from `gsub!`? I don't fully understand the logic behind Ruby's assumption what to return here.

Comment: It generates your desired output. What doesn't work?

Comment: There is room for improvement, but your code works fine. It already achieves the desired output.

Comment: i.e. You can simplify the code to: `my_string.gsub(/\([^)]+\)|\[[^\]]+\]/) { |bracketed| bracketed.tr(' ', '_') }` ... But your version already works??

Comment: @TomLord I suspect OP wants to understand why there is no need to use `return` here, how Ruby modifies the `my_string` from within the block. So, the question is not really about a regex, but about the blocks in general.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that got me confused indeed, but I also messed up later on in my code so it didn't write the changes properly. Your demo was helpful, thanks :) I still find lack of explicit mentioning within a block counter-intuitive…

Comment: @MrVocabularyAs I showed above, you don't even need to put `bracketed = ` in the block! The *last line* of the block (or any method) is an *implicit* response value in ruby.

Comment: *"Why does `bracketed.gsub(/ /, '_')` equal to `bracketed = bracketed.gsub(/ /, '_')`?"* -- they **are not** equal. The first one is an expression that computes a value, the second one is an expression that also computes the same value but then it assigns the value to the local variable `bracketed`; the value of both expressions is the same. The Ruby blocks implicitly return the value of the last computed expression; there is no need to use `return` here to return the value computed by `bracketed.gsub(/ /, '_')`.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-gsub)? _"The value returned by the block will be substituted for the match on each call."_

Comment: @Stefan yes I did, but the fact that blocks in general do that implicity return values was somewhat of a shocker to me.

Comment: @axiac thanks for this explanation. Is that tantamount or similar to how vaiables such as $1 work?

Comment: @MrVocabulary I took that for granted, because most examples with blocks in the documentation like `(1..4).map { |i| i*i } #=> [1, 4, 9, 16]` wouldn't make much sense otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does `bracketed.gsub(/ /, '_')` equal to `bracketed = bracketed.gsub(/ /, '_')`? How is that different from `gsub!`?

- `gsub` returns a **new** string.
- `gsub!` *changes* the **existing** string.

So `bracketed = bracketed.gsub(/ /, '_')` and `bracketed.gsub!(/ /, '_')` are pretty much equivalent.

(There is only a *minor* behavioural difference in that `gsub!` will return `nil` if no pattern was matched. But either way, you'll mutate the original `bracketed` variable in the same way.)

However, you're asking the wrong question... Let's look again at your original code, which could be written as:

```
my_string.gsub!(/\([^)]+\)|\[[^\]]+\]/) do |bracketed|
  bracketed.gsub(/ /, '_')
end
```

From [the documentation for `String#gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub):

> In the block form, the current match string is passed in as a parameter [...] **The value returned by the block will be substituted for the match on each call**.

In ruby, the final evaluated line in a method/block is its *implicit* return value. All you are doing here is passing a value back up to the original `gsub` method; it *doesn't matter* whether or not you mutate/reassign the `bracketed` variable.

Perhaps this example will make things a little clearer:

```
"hello (world)".gsub!(/\([^)]+\)|\[[^\]]+\]/) do |bracketed|
  bracketed = "something different"
  "TEST!!!"
end

  # => "hello (TEST!!!)"
```

Comment: It's not necessarily _"the final line"_, but the last expression evaluated (could be a multi-line `if-elsif-else` construct)

Comment: Okay, I see. I wasn't using the `!` version precisely because of potential `nil`s and was wondering if that implicit thing, but I understand that a lot better now :)

Comment: @Stefan Yeah, sorry -- I really meant "the final line *that gets evaluated*". I'll edit to make that fully clear.